# How can inner elements can be removed when cliking the button

Tags: jquery, html

In my html, i have list of divs inside one div and those each div has checkbox[input type=checkbox].

my aim is when i check the checkbox and when i select the remove button, then, parent div(parent of input:checkbox)  has to be removed, I tried, but, i could not. Any help?

```
$("#delbtn").click(function(e) {
    var divLen=$("#checkbox-content div");

    for(var k=0;k<divLen.length;k++)
    {
        if(divLen[k].children("input").attr("checked")){
            divLen[k].remove();
        }
    }
    return false;
});
```

Html

```
<div id="checkbox-content">
    <div><input type="checkbox" name="checkedvalue"/>Some text</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" name="checkedvalue"/>Some text</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" name="checkedvalue"/>Some text</div>
</div>
<button id="delbtn">Remove</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : remove div which has checkbox checked

```
$("#delbtn").click(function(e) {
    $("#checkbox-content div").has(':checkbox:checked').remove();
 });
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/taenL3t9/)**

Answer (score 1):

Just get the selected checkboxes, reference their parent, and remove it. Nice simple selector + 1 liner.

```
$('#checkbox-content :checkbox:checked').parent().remove();
```

And if "checkbox-content" only contains checkboxes, even smaller line:

```
$('#checkbox-content :checked').parent().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

On button click, check which of the checkboxes are checked and remove their parent elements with their contents.

Check the following code:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#delbtn', function() {
  $('#checkbox-content input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
    var that = $(this);
    if (that.is(':checked')) {
       that.closest('div').remove();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="checkbox-content">
            <div><input type="checkbox" name="checkedvalue"/>Some text one</div>
            <div><input type="checkbox" name="checkedvalue"/>Some text two</div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="checkedvalue"/>Some text three</div>
            </div>
            <button id="delbtn">Remove</button>
```

Comment: This can be simplified greatly. jQuery selectors provide everything you need to do what that logic is doing without the loop or conditional.